# Jquery function should work with subclasses, not for all classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, subclass

A have a this jquery function....

```
$(".rolled-wrap").on('click', function() {
     $(this).each(function() {
        $('.button-text span').text($('.button-text span').data('hover'));
        $('.button-text span').attr("data-hover", $('.button-text span').data('hover'));
    });
});
```

this function need working only for subclasses, current .rolled-wrap (e.g. .rolled-wrap (this) .button-text span)..... however clicking on one class, result summbit for all .button-text span.... I do not know what to do, I will be grateful for any help. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look inside the target element use `.find()`

```
$(".rolled-wrap").on('click', function() {
     $(this).find('.button-text span').text($('.button-text span').data('hover'));
     $(this).find('.button-text span').attr("data-hover", $('.button-text span').data('hover'));
});
```

Comment: yeah man... stack me write u can accept in 8 mins ))) u reply right

Comment: I will definitely notice your answer) I'm sorry newbie